# Creating new list with an operation applied to every element?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list with elements:

> Data = {{1, 2}, {2, 7}, {3, 14}}

This is a list of X and Y coordinates, later used for ListPlot.

For all the Y coordinates I basically want to do Y = 1 / Y, so a new list becomes:

> DataNew={{1, 1/2}, {2, 1/7}, {3, 1/14}}

How would I do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also for example:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {2, 7}, {3, 14}};
newData = data /. {x_, y_} -> {x, 1/y}
```

or

```
newData = Cases[data, {x_, y_} -> {x, 1/y}]
```

or

```
f[{a_, b_}] := {a, 1/b};
newData = f /@ data
```

and zillions of other possibilities.

Remember to start all your defined names with lowercase letters!

Comment: Sorry, but I must down-vote this.  Reasoning given in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

With `data = {{1, 2}, {2, 7}, {3, 14}}` I recommend:

```
{#, 1/#2} & @@@ data
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
Replace[data, {x_, y_} :> {x, 1/y}, {1}]
```

I recommend against using either of these:

```
data /. {x_, y_} -> {x, 1/y}

Cases[data, {x_, y_} -> {x, 1/y}]
```

Both incorrectly use `Rule` rather than `RuleDelayed`, which means they fail to localize the named patterns.  Also, the first is not good because of the ambiguity it introduces:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 7}} /. {x_, y_} :> {x, 1/y}
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1/2, 1/7}}
> ```

The second is less troublesome, but IMHO since `Cases` is a filtering function it should not be used where you really want `Replace`, as this makes code less clear.

---

Leonid reminds us that my recommended method does not auto-compile in cases where that is possible (such as a packed array of Reals).  If performance is critical it is usually fastest to use the double `Transpose` method compared below.

```
dat = RandomReal[99, {50000, 2}];

Do[ {#, 1/#2} & @@@ dat , {50}] // Timing

Do[ Transpose[{#, 1/#2} & @@ Transpose@dat] , {50}] // Timing
```

> {2.074, Null}
>
> {0.032, Null}

Comment: A good addition. I also agree that `@@@` looks nicer, and one can usually tune the performance when it is needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use :

```
{#[[1]], 1/#[[2]]} & /@ Data
```